# System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I am returning the result as:

```
 return DataTablesResult.Create(
            catalogues, 
            dataTableParam,
            uv => new {
                PendingCopies = (uv.Status.Equals((int)Services.Sequester.CitedWorkStatus.Uncatalogued) || uv.Status.Equals((int)Services.Sequester.CitedWorkStatus.Unapproved)) ? uv.PendingCopies + 1 : uv.PendingCopies,
                StatusName = ((Services.Sequester.CitedWorkStatus)uv.Status).ToString().Replace("_", " "),
                IconSet = this.RenderPartialViewToString("Buttons/_gridIconSetCatalogue", new Int32[] {uv.MaterialId, uv.Status})
             }
        );
```

There are only 183 records in the table But it throws an exception:

> System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably you haven't dispose every previous returned result sets which still stored in memory while executing the query. Use either `using` block to release resources, split the query execution with `Skip` and `Take` methods or adding `GC.Collect` after executing query (remember that `Dispose` method may or may not work depending on result types).